# Finding out the OS my PHP script is run on

Tags: php, operating-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the OS on which PHP is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482260/how-to-get-the-os-on-which-php-is-running)

I need my script to be able to recognize whether it's being run on a Windows or on a Linux system so it can behave accordingly. How do I do that?

EDIT: I need a definite way of doing that, that has no risk of recognizing the wrong OS.

Comment: I actually did a couple of searches and didn't come across that. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php_uname` and/or the `PHP_OS` constant will tell you. See the examples here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the `php_uname()` function?

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php

Answer (score 1):

`if (PHP_OS == 'Linux') echo 'Linux os!'`

Answer (score 1):

predefined constant: `PHP_OS` ........

Comment: I would prefer this solution as it gives a more direct piece of information as per which operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [second link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php) if I google 'os php':

Answer (score -2):

Note that anything that comes from the browser to your code can be spoofed, so it's not 'definite'.

Comment: Its about the OS the script is running.