# php change directory to base directory

Tags: php

i change the dir to the current file directory to :

```
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
```

But how do i change it back to the base director like `/` in linux and say `C:` in windows i dont know that is the OS of the user.

Is there a way to do it in both linux and win ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP will translate directory separators for you, so just `chdir('/')` will work on both. However, you'd have to account for Windows drive names, as there's no such thing on Unix systems.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question: [How to get the OS on which PHP is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482260/how-to-get-the-os-on-which-php-is-running) might help you determine the OS.

Try using [`php_uname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php)