# Get the Linux distribution name in PHP

Tags: php, linux, operating-system, linux-distro

Is there a way in PHP to figure out the Linux distribution name of a remote server?

Extracting from `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` is just the OS name of the client's machine. It is not what I want. I tried [php_uname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php)

```
echo 'Operating System: '.php_uname('s').'<br>'; // echo PHP_OS;
echo 'Release Name: '.php_uname('r').'<br>';
echo 'Version: '.php_uname('v').'<br>';
echo 'Machine Type: '.php_uname('m').'<br>';
```

But the mode `s` returns only the kernel type - Linux.

```
Operating System: Linux
Release Name: 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64
Version: #1 SMP Tue Sep 9 21:36:05 UTC 2014
Machine Type: x86_64
```

I want to know it is Fedora, CentOS or Ubuntu, etc. Is it possible? I have also tried [posix_uname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-uname.php), but got an error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function posix_uname()

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I interpret the output of php\_uname](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129737/how-do-i-interpret-the-output-of-php-uname)

Comment: No, not a duplicate, because it asks for the distribution, not the platform.

Answer (score 3):

On a Linux system, there are usually files like `/etc/lsb-release` or `/etc/os-release` which contain information about the distribution.

You can read them in PHP and extract their values:

```php
if (strtolower(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 5)) === 'linux')
{
    $vars = array();
    $files = glob('/etc/*-release');

    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        $lines = array_filter(array_map(function($line) {

            // split value from key
            $parts = explode('=', $line);

            // makes sure that "useless" lines are ignored (together with array_filter)
            if (count($parts) !== 2) return false;

            // remove quotes, if the value is quoted
            $parts[1] = str_replace(array('"', "'"), '', $parts[1]);
            return $parts;

        }, file($file)));

        foreach ($lines as $line)
            $vars[$line[0]] = $line[1];
    }

    print_r($vars);
}
```

(Not the most elegant PHP code, but it gets the job done.)

This will give you an array like:

```
Array
(
    [DISTRIB_ID] => Ubuntu
    [DISTRIB_RELEASE] => 13.04
    [DISTRIB_CODENAME] => raring
    [DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION] => Ubuntu 13.04
    [NAME] => Ubuntu
    [VERSION] => 13.04, Raring Ringtail
    [ID] => ubuntu
    [ID_LIKE] => debian
    [PRETTY_NAME] => Ubuntu 13.04
    [VERSION_ID] => 13.04
    [HOME_URL] => http://www.ubuntu.com/
    [SUPPORT_URL] => http://help.ubuntu.com/
    [BUG_REPORT_URL] => http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/
)
```

The `ID` field is best suited to determine the distribution, as it's defined by the Linux Standard Base and should be present on common distributions.

By the way, I would recommend not using `exec()` or `system()` to read files, because they are disabled on many servers for security reasons. (Also, it doesn't make sense, because PHP can natively read files. And if it can't read them, then it also won't be possible though a system call.)

Comment: Thanks. Can you please add a web link for the function `glob`, e.g,. from php manual? And why you use it? Is there any advantage over the ordinary file/dir functions?

Comment: And your code is not working. It issues `500 Internal Server Error`.

Comment: https://php.net/glob … the 500 error may have been caused by the new array syntax. I have changed it to the old one (PHP < 5.4) now. If it still doesn't work, please check your error logs for the actual error message, or increase the error reporting level.

Comment: Yes, PHP in my server is 5.3. It seems working now, unfortunately it just output an empty array. Please [check here](http://sithukyaw.com/server2.php). It is not my ordinary server in this question, but same result. BTW, the link here is running on a sharing hosting where I found that `exec()` is working too. [Check it here](http://sithukyaw.com/server.php).

Comment: `exec()` and `glob` are disabled in Web IDE like phpfiddle.org

Comment: `exec` is indeed disabled on most hosts. `glob` however is available on most hosts; also, it's used by many common PHP applications. Instead of using `glob`, you could also check for the existence of the aforementioned files directly.

Answer (score 2):

Try a PHP `system($call)` call http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php
There you can do whatever you want to find out the desired infomation, on an ubuntu system, you might for example want to use `system('cat /etc/issue');`
You might want to use an approach, where you call a bash script from PHP, for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/how-can-i-get-distribution-name-and-version-number-in-a-simple-shell-script

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make system calls and the commands or locations of where that info can be obtained can vary by distro.  Here is code that queries the most common locations in a cascading fashion until it finds the answer:

```
$linux_distro = null;
$os_info = file_exists("/etc/os-release") ? explode("\n", shell_exec("cat /etc/os-release")) : [];
foreach ($os_info as $line) {
    if (preg_match('/^ID=(")?[a-zA-Z]+(")?/i', trim($line))) {
        $linux_distro = strtolower(preg_replace('/(^ID=(")?|")/i', "", trim($line)));
        break;
    }
}
if (!$linux_distro) {
    $hostnamectl_available = shell_exec("command -v hostnamectl");
    $os_info = ($hostnamectl_available) ? explode("\n", shell_exec("hostnamectl")) : [];
    foreach ($os_info as $line) {
        if (preg_match('/^Operating System:\s+/i', trim($line))) {
            $linux_distro = strtolower(preg_replace('/(^Operating System:\s+)([\w]+)\b(.*)?/i', "$2", trim($line)));
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (!$linux_distro) {
    $lsb_release_available = shell_exec("command -v lsb_release");
    $os_info = ($lsb_release_available) ? explode("\n", shell_exec("lsb_release -a")) : [];
    foreach ($os_info as $line) {
        if (preg_match('/^Distributor ID:\s+/i', trim($line))) {
            $linux_distro = strtolower(preg_replace('/(^Distributor ID:\s+)([\w]+)\b(.*)?/i', "$2", trim($line)));
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (!$linux_distro) {
    $os_info = file_exists("/etc/system-release") ? shell_exec("cat /etc/system-release") : "";
    $linux_distro = ($os_info) ? strtolower(preg_replace('/^([\w]+)\b(.*)?/', "$1", trim($os_info))) : "not found";
}
if (preg_match('/^(red|redhatlinux|rhel|redhatenterpriseserver|redhatenterpriselinux)$/', $linux_distro))
    $linux_distro = "redhat";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

[The possible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129737/how-do-i-interpret-the-output-of-php-uname) mentioned above is expensive to find out the distributions. I got a quick and simple solution using [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and executing the command:

```
$cmd = 'cat /etc/*-release';
exec($cmd, $output);
print_r($output);
```

then, it results.

```
Array
(
    [0] => CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
    [1] => CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
    [2] => CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
)
```

Credits: [HowTo: Find Out My Linux Distribution Name and Version](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-linux-distribution-name-version-number/)

Comment: (1) Your command would return an error due to the duplicate `cat`. (2) See my answer for a pure PHP solution. Using `exec` here is bad, because if you want to maintain portability, you should avoid functions that are likely to be disabled on many hosts.

Comment: @lxg It did not return an error and it did work, though it was my typo.

Comment: @lxg Thanks for your answer, but your solution gave me 500 error and nothing output. Please see my comment in your answer. In my experience, most of the time, `exec` does work in my servers, probably it is because of VPS with root access. It may not work in shared hostings as your concern.