# PHP on Windows - check if working in background

Tags: php, windows

I have Windows 10 with xampp installed.
Let's assume I have a PHP script, containing

```
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);

$counter = 0;

while($counter < 60){
    file_put_contents('runtime_log.txt', $counter." \r\n", FILE_APPEND);
    $counter++;
    sleep(1);
}
```

I can close the browser window and the script will be still writing output to runtime_log.txt
If I wanted to check if it's running in the background on Linux, I would use

```
ps aux | grep php
```

How to do the same thing on Windows?

**EDIT:** I have simplified my question, because I can see that it's been misunderstood.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the OS on which PHP is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482260/how-to-get-the-os-on-which-php-is-running)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/18830/is-there-a-command-in-windows-like-ps-aux-in-unix you need command `tasklist`

Comment: @vadim_hr I have tried to use it, but it doesn't show any php.exe processes.

Comment: probably process is not php.exe, but apache or similar. what about using this utility https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle ? you can check if file `runtime_log.txt` is still in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get that information directly from the process list in Windows, because by default Apache is configured to load PHP as a module (a .DLL) so it will not be listed as a different process when it's running (unless PHP is configured to run as CGI, but nowadays that option is not used anymore).

I think that you can search for that using [Process explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), open it and then search (with the binoculars icon) for opened handles for `runtime_log.txt`, if the file is opened by PHP an open handle should appear for the `httpd` (Apache) process (this is method I use for finding the program that prevents me from deleting a file).

Note that you probably need to run Process Explorer elevated (as an administrator) since Apache is running as system service.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put too much effort, just use the constant `PHP_OS` as also described  here: [How to get the OS on which PHP is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482260/how-to-get-the-os-on-which-php-is-running)